# How do you add a watermark on a DOC file in C#? Not DOCX file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

We have found some codes on how to add text watermark on DOCX file but we can't find one for DOC files. Please, help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use Spire.Doc for .NET i am not sure it is freeware or not:**

**This might helpful to you:**
Here 's https://www.e-iceblue.com/Download/download-word-for-net-now.html

**Documentation:** 
Visit https://www.e-iceblue.com/Knowledgebase/Spire.Doc/Program-Guide/How-to-insert-a-watermark-into-Word.html?__c=1

Comment: Yep. Spire.Doc is not free but I found other way to watermark a document (DOCX and DOC). I used Microsoft.Office.Interop. It can also work with Excel files which is what I am looking for. Thanks for the suggestion man.